# Distributive property conjunction / existential quantifier

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Given the following predicate;

$(\exists x:X.P(x)\implies Q(x)) \wedge \forall y:X.P(y)$

Applying the distributive property of $\wedge$ / $\exists$

$\equiv \exists x:X.(P(x)\implies Q(x)) \wedge \forall y:X.P(y) $

Can you always 'move a universal quantifier under' an existential quantifier? (I'm not sure how to properly express this in English.)

What are the restrictions for applying this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that works!

The general principle is:

$\exists x \ \varphi(x) \land \psi \equiv \exists x (\varphi(x) \land \psi)$

where $\psi$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable.

And that applies here. The fact that in this case the $\psi$ contains a universal quantifier does not change this. In fact, even if you had $\forall x : X . P(x)$ on the right side it would still work, since it would still be true that $x$ is not a free variable in that formula.